# Form action submit for Electron desktop app

Tags: javascript, php, html, desktop-application, electron

This is my first time building a desktop app using electron/node.js and I have no experience bulding web apps.

I am trying to add a submit form to my app.

I tried to replicate the tutorials (w3), but keep getting the same error message:

```
Not allowed to load local resource:
```

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zStT.png)

[action_page.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7o7z.png)

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Please post your code **not** pictures of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set up the root in your Electron app, the app.js code needs to change.

In the callback function within

```
app.on('ready', function(){
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 600,
        width: 800
    });

    mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/app/index.html');
});
```

You need to set up the mainWindow's path, which has to be the remote path to your PHP code.

So if you have www.example.com as your web app you want to use within your Electron app, you need to specify that url in the mainwindow. It basically functions as a wrapped browser then.

Basically, Electron is only a browser, it does not magically render PHP pages for you, you still need a server to render them for you. So you cannot load in .php files locally, unless you have a server running locally. Still, if you do, you still need a valid URL to enter there along the lines of:

```
http://localhost:9000
```

or something similiar.